# libclang not emitting certain AST nodes

Tags: clang, libclang

I'm using the [go-clang](https://github.com/sbinet/go-clang) library to parse the following C file: [aac.c](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/a3f0577ed04b6c469cd8c282522893364bebcf3f/sys/dev/aac/aac.c). For some reason when I run the file through clang and dump the AST, I don't get AST output for certain functions. For example, the C file contains a [forward declaration of `aac_ioctl_send_raw_srb`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/a3f0577ed04b6c469cd8c282522893364bebcf3f/sys/dev/aac/aac.c#L196) and the [actual definition](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/a3f0577ed04b6c469cd8c282522893364bebcf3f/sys/dev/aac/aac.c#L3047) later on in the file.

Given this I was expecting to see two AST nodes in the output but only one `FuncDecl` (the forward declaration) is dumped:

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only aac.c | grep "aac_ioctl_send_raw_srb" | wc -l
aac.c:38:10: fatal error: 'opt_aac.h' file not found
#include "opt_aac.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
       1 <--- wc output
```

(Ignoring the error)

I get the same result using the go-clang library to parse the C file from within my own application. Is there any explanation for why the definition is not dumped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help in `#llvm` IRC and someone suggested that the errors actually *are* causing the issue. Even though *other* nodes are being emitted, LLVM may just be ignoring ones that it thinks require information that reside in the missing `#include`s.

I fixed the include paths and sure enough the nodes I was looking for were emitted.